# Android: "Element intent-filter is not allowed here" inside <provider>?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-xml, storage-access-framework

At http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#manifest it is shown how to register a custom document provider in the manifest:

```
<manifest... >
    ...
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
        ....
        <provider
            android:name="com.example.android.storageprovider.MyCloudProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.storageprovider.documents"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"
            android:enabled="@bool/atLeastKitKat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </provider>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This <intent-filter> element is necessary here, but Android Studio complains with:

> Element intent-filter is not allowed here

and [the documentation for the provider element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html) seems to indicate so as well:

```
CAN CONTAIN:
<meta-data> 
<grant-uri-permission> 
<path-permission>
```

Is this an Android Studio and documentation bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Reported as a bug at: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218872

Comment: I starred your bug report, but history suggests it's likely to be ignored. Only a fraction of the bugs filed against Android ever get an official comment let alone a fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not missing anything; Android Studio and the documentation are incorrect. Providers are subject to discovery through intent matching, just like any other component.

Android finds document providers using code like this:

> Intent i = new Intent([DocumentsContract.PROVIDER_INTERFACE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#PROVIDER_INTERFACE));
>
> List<ResolveInfo> providers = [packageManager.queryIntentContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentContentProviders(android.content.Intent,%20int))(i, 0);